# How many parallel processes does a Quantum Computer Have?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, computer

I know that quantum computers have a extremely large capacity to do many different calculations at once, but *how* many different calculations? Is it infinite, like I've heard some articles say, or is it the number of Qubits in a given quantum computer, or is it linked in some other way to the number of Qubits?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on what, exactly, you intend to do, and what, exactly, a "thing" is. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, basically, how many different calculations can it do at the same time (similar to cores in regular processors)

Comment: Ultimately, it depends on what you mean by "calculation". There is no "quantum CPU" at this point, no general-purpose quantum computer. What we have are quantum circuits, similar to the digital logic circuits of the very early days of computing. Each circuit is designed to do a particular thing, i.e. implement a particular algorithm. If you allow quantum circuits of arbitrary complexity, then you can make the circuit as parallel as you want just by duplicating it. But you can also do this with classical digital logic circuits.

Comment: So the sensible comparison to classical computing at present would be closer to an FPGA, rather than a CPU. Even then, your question currently isn't clear whether it refers to what's possible _theoretically_ or what's practical _with current technology_. If you mean theoretically, then if you have an infinitely big FPGA, you can perform an infinite number of calculations at the same time.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this question might stem from the misconception I heard said that quantum computers are more powerful because they can "try multiple solutions at once", that is not how a quantum computer works, despite what some pop-sci sources say.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: quantum computers do not run many classical computations in parallel. They implement a different kind of computations, which can solve *specific* problems faster than classical computers can.

This question seems to be based on a misconception, commonly propagated in popular science accounts of quantum computing, according to which quantum algorithms "explore infinite possibilities", "try multiple solutions at once" or something along those lines.

Quantum computers are *not* fast because they do many classical calculations in parallel. GPUs can do many calculations in parallel, and that is why they are effective in some areas of scientific computing, but that is entirely within classical computation.

Quantum computers are made with qubits, and quantum algorithms are built with operations on such qubit. This is generally a completely different way to do calculations, which in some cases leads to algorithms that can quickly solve *specific* problems that are hard on a classical computer.
The most famous example is probably integer factorisation into primes. That does not work because a quantum computer can execute classical algorithms in a fast way. It works because people came up with *quantum* algorithms (famously [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), but there are others).

This is explained better e.g. [here](https://medium.com/quantum1net/3-common-misconceptions-about-quantum-computing-5d93465ff153),
and in a cheeky way in [this comic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3).

Comment: This answer was meant to present links to online resources that explain the misconception the question is based on. I wrote a few paragraphs to make it self-contained an not link-only.
I recall reading a much better explanation somewhere, but I don't remember the source or author, so feel free to modify/add links.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on type of task you solve. For example for integer factorization, a quantum computer brings exponential speed-up. So, it seems (no actually, it is only popular notion) that the number of parallel processes is $2^n$ ($n$ being number of qubits). In case of searching in unordered database (Grover algorithm) the speed-up is only quadratic. There are also some tasks (such as binary function calculation) where quantum computer is equally fast as classical computer.

Number of qubits of course tells you about a capacity of quantum computer. More qubits means that you can represent more values and solve bigger problems. But as I showed above, it also depends on task you are solving.

Additionaly, I would correct one inaccuracy in your question. In fact, quantum computers do not do parallel processes. It is a way how to explain their higher performance to laymen. Actual speed-up in particular task has to be derived by complex mathematical calculation and reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

A quantum calculation can run a vast number of processes in parallel, but at the end of the calculation a measurement is performed that yields a value corresponding to only one randomly selected possible outcome out of all those processes. Quantum advantage depends on clever design of the processes and the way their possible outcomes are combined before the measurement is done.

Measurement of a single qbit can only yield a 1 or a zero, but the relative probability of 1 vs zero can have a continuous range of values - an infinite number of possible values. Unfortunately, quantum mechanics makes it impossible to do a single measurement that determines the precise relative probability: the only way to "measure" the relative probability is to do a very large number of measurements and count how many 1's vs 0's you get.

Clever design of the quantum processes might allow N qbits to yield the equivalent of N single-qbit measurements; or it might allow the N qbits to yield the equivalent of a single measurement of an N-element vector.  In the latter case, the final result of repeating the processes and measurements many times would yield an N-element vector whose elements have real values ranging between 1 and 0.

Answer (score -1):

The number of calculations that a quantum computer can do depends on the number of qubits it has and the type of algorithms that runs on it. With N qubits in a quantum computer, it is possible to represent all 2^N combinations simultaneously (which is not possible in classical computer) and a suitable algorithm like Grover can detect the required combination in one attempt. But, in order to get the answer outside the quantum computer, Grover algorithm needs sqrt(N) calculations.
Like this, many algorithms are being developed to speed up the computation but the size of the problem still depends on the size (number of qubits) of the quantum computer.